# Frontier EVM integration: UnknownTransaction::NoUnsignedValidator error occurs while transferring funds via Metamask

Tags: rpc, frontier, evm, metamask

I'm integrating Frontier EVM into my Substrate chain and facing the following issue while trying to send some funds between accounts via metamask:

```
[ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"code":-32603,"message":"submit transaction to pool failed: Ok(UnknownTransaction(UnknownTransaction::NoUnsignedValidator))"}}}'
```

Seems like I've integrated everything that was required using the frontier repo as an example:

- Runtime configuration
- RPC services
- Chain spec
- Node service configuration

So the blockchain starts well, everything works fine, Metamask connects to the node RPC endpoint and successfully reads the pre-funded accounts.

However when I'm trying to transfer some chain tokens to another account it fails.

[image]

Perhaps I missed something while configuring the node but I can't get the exact reason.

Have someone faced this problem? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by myself by providing `fp_self_contained::UncheckedExtrinsic` for `UncheckedExtrinsic` type. Then it started to use self contained call for eth like calls.